# WSO2 Postgres db locking for long time

Tags: postgresql, wso2-identity-server

We're running into WSO2 Identity Server issues like Admin(Carbon console) user, Normal user(Service provider) unable to login, basically not able to do any operations.

Upon looking into logs, we found that it's because postgres db is getting blocked in one specific scenario which we were able to figure out as mentioned below:

Whenever SCIM2 GROUP PATCH request is made to add a group member who is already present in the same group and when the group member count is more database is being blocked.

This isn't valid scenario, which we later handled at our application end to not add same group member(Also, opted for SCIM2 Bulk API as it won't return all members back to improve performance). But now we're not sure, if we won't run into such issues again. Some times, we're having to restart the server.

So I wanted to know if there are known solutions for such issues. Is there any way, we can reduce DB blocking time.

IS v5.10.0

Comment: Response of the SCIM2 GROUP PATCH API in such cases: 
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "detail": "Error occurred while getting database type from DB connection",
    "status": "500"
}

Comment: [2021-07-05 22:24:19,059] [2af9d2de-bad0-4a2a-8b3b-a41ca919fd62] ERROR 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} - 
Error while retrieving roles from Internal JDBC role store org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) 
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268)

Comment: what is the postgre version you are using? Seems like the error is originating from postgre.